# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 realtime color changing

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors, shader

At the moment I am creating a new shader program every frame and using it to color a shape. This causes a fair amount of lag. I was wondering if there was any way to set the color of an object more efficiently in GLES20. I know in other versions there is a setColor function, but as far as I can tell it doesn't exist in this version of OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use uniform variables. You will have something like this in the declaration part of your fragment shader:

```
uniform vec4 objColor;
```

Then you use this value to set your object color.

In your Java (I figure it's Java since you have an Android tag) code, you have the following after linking your shader program, with `progId` being the id of the program you just linked:

```
objColorLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(progId, "objColor");
```

Then, before making your draw call, change the color with:

```
GLES20.glUniform4f(objColorLoc, colR, colG, colB, 1.0f);
```